# create a new column by merge two existing columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two columns `SE_track` and `identifier` and I want to merge these two columns into a third column called `subgroup`.

I have used this:

```
names(incl_vs_not)
unite(incl_vs_not, subgroup, c(SE_track, identifier), remove=FALSE)
```

I do not get any error message, but my dataframe `incl_vs_not` has the same amount of columns it had before, so i think nothing happened. I also cannot see any column called `subgroup`

**What is wrong with this**

**Is there an alternative solution?**

Comment: I think the issue may just be that you aren't assigning the results of `unite(incl_vs_not, subgroup, c(SE_track, identifier), remove=FALSE)` to anything. If you try `incl_vs_not<-unite(incl_vs_not, subgroup, c(SE_track, identifier), remove=FALSE)`, does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand what you are trying to achieve:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c("a1","a2","a3"),b=c("b1","b2","b3"))
df$ab<-paste(df$a,df$b,sep="_")
```